# Transitioning an element from its current position to the center of the viewport?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

Transitioning an element from its current position to the center of the viewport?

That's basically all I'm asking.

I want the elem to smoothly move to the center of the image from wherever it is on the page using something like a checkbox to toggle between the states.

I really really want to do this with pure CSS. Can it be done?

Comment: Please provide example HTML and CSS code that can be modified to achieve this goal. A question like this needs a little more context in order to provide an answer.

Comment: http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/MwYgVY When you click the pig, it janks its way to the given position, how do I make that a smooth transition?

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVEYZm

Try something like this. The problem was that you did not specify a `transform` or a `top` and `left` in the default state, so the CSS transition does not know how to calculate from an undefined state to a defined one when the check is toggled.

```
img {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    /* these need to be specified as well */
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

input:checked {
    + label {
        img {
            /* since they're the values being transitioned */
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I kinda knew that already (don't mean to sound like a jerk). I want that result but without having to specify a top and left.

Comment: @mildrenben - why is there a requirement that top and left not be specified? And if you knew that already it should have been in your question.

Comment: @mildrenben your request is not possible then, using pure CSS. Perhaps you should ask a new question about this, requesting a solution in JavaScript with the restriction that a ``top`` and ``left`` are not defined in the initial CSS state. Meanwhile, my answer to your original question is in fact correct and should be accepted.